# $injector.modulerr issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, ngroute

So I've been racking my brains for some time, looked at each and every line and I can't seem to find any mistake. Here are my codes:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul ng-controller="pathController">
      <li ng-click="changePath('about')"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li ng-click="changePath('contacts')"><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
      <li ng-click="changePath('login')"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      <li ng-click="changePath('register')"><a href="#register">Join Now</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/pathController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngController']);

app.config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider"], 
  function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix("");
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: "index.html"
  })
})
```

*About that 'ngController' dependency - I added it afterwards, in the process of checking different things which could possibly fix it.*

and pathController.js:

```
app.controller('pathController', function($scope) {
  $scope.changePath = function(pth) {
    window.location.pathname = pth;
  }
})
```

As you can see, $routeProvider is not the issue. Please take a look and see if you can solve my problem.

P.S. *I am sorry, I forgot to add the error that I am getting, I only wrote it in the title, here it is:*

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.4/ ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ngController` is not a module. You don't need to include it as a dependency

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Please fix the error link, it's currently useless. Don't copy it from your console, visit the link then copy it from your address bar. Use the un-minified version of Angular for better error messages

Comment: Alexxar, fixed ur issue,  check my answer. It was minor syntactical error ;) CHeers

Comment: When add additional broken code to your question, it distracts from the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", 
 function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix("");
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: "index.html"
 })
 }]
)
```

You have made below error:

app.config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider"`]`,  <-- this ] bracket should not be closed here.

[Here is the working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bTWrvikSYUOvxLb9WmZG?p=preview)

Comment: Nicely spotted!

Comment: @Phil ;) Thanks mate

Comment: @Alexxar : Hehe... Happy coding.. Upvote as well ,if u feel like :P